# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and Tangible T4 Editor Pro v1.950 Crashing

Tags: windows-7, t4, visual-studio-2010, tangible-t4-editor

Error Says

> I'm missing
>   ActiproSoftware.CSharpHostLanguage.xml
>   from
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\4WT9GZ6E.WD1\0CNLWRJ6.ODR\3f01d2db\26ba7213_ebf0cb01
>   and crashes when opening a .tt or
>   .ttinclude file.

I have visual studio 2010 sp1 and windows 7 sp1 x86 (32bit).

Tangible T4 Editor is v1.950.

Any suggestions are welcome.  Thanks.

UPDATE: Latest build 1.962 fixes this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did post a new build today, that fixes the path to the install dir instead of taking the path relative to the assembly loaded. That should resolve the issue for anyone. Reason is still unkown why this happend on that box.

Comment: The new build works great.  Thanks so much for the quick help.  Just an FYI I have many gallery addons installed for Visual Studio, not sure if this could have caused the original issue but like I said the new build fixed it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

That is really odd. The path specified does not belong to tangible t4. There are two possible reasons for this:

1. You are using some sort of Application Virtualisation - we have not yet tested the product with.
2. You are using another product that uses actipro dlls and those were registed in other location and accidentaly loaded from there. I am not aware of any incompatabilites here: Product that use actirpo are Expression Web and Webmatrix as well as many other code generators and LinqPad.

Comment: For those flagging as spam ... this is the CEO offering help ... nice guy!

Comment: if possible, can you post the solution (if found). So other people can benefit from this. (And please remove the email if the call has been entered, unless you want lots of spam). ;-).

Comment: Clearing the spam flags here, this is certainly **not** spam - and we appreciate the direct help Tim!